# How can I let top show in byte for memory usage on MacOS?

Tags: macos, mac

I use below command to show memory and cpu usage on MacOS but it shows in `G` not `byte`. How can I make it show byte in the output?

```
$ top -l 1 -n 0
Processes: 432 total, 2 running, 430 sleeping, 2306 threads 
2018/01/16 11:23:44
Load Avg: 2.54, 4.00, 5.70 
CPU usage: 6.58% user, 10.63% sys, 82.78% idle 
SharedLibs: 193M resident, 55M data, 24M linkedit.
MemRegions: 166609 total, 6388M resident, 85M private, 1820M shared.
PhysMem: 15G used (3079M wired), 593M unused.
VM: 3253G vsize, 1098M framework vsize, 10135734(0) swapins, 11401593(0) swapouts.
Networks: packets: 3462765/3440M in, 2340820/1677M out.
Disks: 6698979/126G read, 3697913/112G written.
```

Answer (score 1):

Any command you enter in Terminal.app provides help with the "man" command. For a list of the options on "top" you would type in:

```
man top
```

I had a quick look through the options and I did not see anything that allowed you to change the displayed memory units. Perhaps if you had a closer look?

Wondering if there is a way to feed the output through something else that would convert to bytes. Possible but that is beyond my meagre CLI skills...